# Splitting html tags in jquery

Tags: jquery

How would I split this value in jquery. I was going to use the split function but thought there might be an easier way.

```
var location = <span class="title">Greenbeck</span><br>9th Street<br>2554 glockcove<br>State, OX 10025<a class="loc" href="#" title="More info">Click For More Info</a>
```

I want to split it so I get this result.
Greenbeck 9th Street glockcove State, OX 10025

I was going to use split like this.
var spl = location.split('
', location.length);
And then split it again using  and then again with a and so on but it seems like there is a n easier an more efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as suggested map is the right way to filter and join and you need .contents() to retrieve even text nodes, so :

```
var plainAddress = $('<div>'+location+'</div>').contents().map(function(){
    var e = $(this);
    return (e.is('a') || e.is('br')) ? null : e.text();
}).get().join(' ');
// ouptput : 'Greenbeck 9th Street 2554 glockcove State, OX 10025'
```

be carefull with remove or detach because they modify the dom tree, it is different than filter a collection result...

Comment: `.remove()` and `.detach()` only modify the DOM tree if they are used in the context of the DOM tree ==> e.g. `$("a").remove();`, not if they're used in some other context ==> e.g. $`("a", $someOtherContext).remove();`

Comment: you're right...I mean modify any virtual or not dom tree, it is just because it is a pitty to modify one tree when you just have to filter, that is less heavy operations...

Answer (score 0):

$('selector').text() give the inside plain text of element, so you may try to wrap and text (didn't try) :

```
var plainAddress = $('<div>'+location+'</div>').text();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately that's an even worse result. Greenbeck9th Street2554 glockcoveState, OX 10025Click For More Info

Comment: This also show the text within the link - `Click for More Info`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 var location = $('<div><span class="title">Greenbeck</span><br>9th Street<br>2554 glockcove<br>State, OX 10025<a class="loc" href="#" title="More info">Click For More Info</a></div>');
location.find('a.loc').detach();
console.log(location.text());
```

Comment: This is close but I need it to be separated. Your result gave me Greenbeck9th Street2554 glockcoveState, OX 10025. When it should be like the example in my post above. Greenbeck 9th Street glockcove State, OX 10025. Anyway I can do this but have them separated.

Comment: Also why would I have to wrap it again in a div tag like you have done

Comment: No need to use [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) unless you want to store what you've [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)ed.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a smidgen of raw Javascript and follow up with jQuery:

1. [**`.replace()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the `<br>`s with spaces
2. [**`.append()`**](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the string to a `DIV` to make using jQuery on it easy.
3. [**`.remove()`**](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) those pesky `A` tags from the [**context**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context) of your jQuery object.
4. Show just the [**`.text()`**](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

.

```
var $html, result, location = '...';

$html = $("<div></div>").append(location.replace(/<br>/gi, " "));
$("a", $html).remove();
result = $html.text();
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/FAwga/)

Answer (score -1):

It's actually much easier if you do it in jQuery:

Assuming that location is a string, you can instantly turn it into a jquery object: `$(location)`

Now that it is an object, you can iterate through each one: `$(location).each()`

Or you can map it into an object or array: `myArr = $(location).map()`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/yZaAm/

Keep in mind that you have to strip out blank elements

Comment: Hey rkw I like that style. simple. I tried to use YSRB detach method to remove the a tag before I do the each loop. But it did'nt detach the a tag. http://jsfiddle.net/yZaAm/2/ I need to remove the click for more info at the end of the string